# grid loading effect - css with filter option - js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using grid loading effect to show my image gallery. Today I decided to add a filter option to the gallery, but I encounter a problem. When I use one of the filter options the images do not slide up together, but stay in the same position they were when all images are showed. Is there any way to make them slide together?

This is what I use for gallery: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/02/loading-effects-for-grid-items-with-css-animations/
And for the filter: http://www.picssel.com/create-a-filtered-image-gallery-with-jquery-and-fancybox/

I tried to put it all together in jsfiddle, but for some reasone the grid loading effect did not work there! So this is what I am using so far: http://pastebin.com/NpuKRJvb

Here is the pics. 
All: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygNf4.jpg
Filter: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajz2v.jpg

I also want to point out that I'm not very familiar with javascript.

p.s. Sorry for my bad English. If there are mistakes please edit, so I could learn! :)